# How do I calculate prediction intervals for random forest predictions?

Tags: bootstrap, random-forest, prediction-interval

In regression problems random forests yield a prediction for each case by averaging the results of each single tree in the forest. I would like to draw a 95% prediction interval around each prediction. There is a nice option `interval="prediction"` for the prediction method of linear models, but there's no such thing for random forests (at least in the R package randomForest). Can I presume that the casewise predictions of the single trees are normally distributed and apply the formula http://mathurl.com/bbvuvx9 or should I determine it by bootstrapping? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the continuous response case.  If so, I'd recommend the `quantregForest` package that layers on top of the basic `randomForest` package and gives conditional quantile predictions.  The documentation is quite good.  Instead of assuming a gaussian distribution, it build an empirical density function from the terminal nodes.

Comment: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~meinshau/quantregforests.pdf describes the technique.

Comment: @Shea Parkes: I did not know this package, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @B_Miner: I already downloaded the pdf and shall dig into it... Certainly I'll come back with more questions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `ranger` package supports quantile predictions and hence prediction intervals: `predict(ranger_fit, type = "quantile", quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975))`.